# jQuery/jQuery mobile tap/swipe event

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

Hi im trying call this function from an element, but the element id is dynamic.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#showme_').live('swiperight',function(event) {
    $("#showDel_").show(); 
});
</script>
```

if a user swipes on an element is shows the delete button.

```
<div id="swipeme_1">swipe me
<div id="showDel_1" style="display:none;">DELETE</div>
</div>

<div id="swipeme_2">swipe me
<div id="showDel_2" style="display:none;">DELETE</div>
</div>

<div id="swipeme_2">swipe me
<div id="showDel_3" style="display:none;">DELETE</div>
</div>
```

i can achieve the same effect by looping the javascript in with the backend code of the site. is there another/easier way?

Regards

Comment: example, if you have used the fb app on the iphone, swipe right on status to show delete button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know which plugin you are using for `swiperlight` event. But if you are not using `touchwipe` plugin then I would suggest you to take a look at this

http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

**Sample code**

```
$("#showme_").touchwipe({
     wipeLeft: function() { alert("left"); },
     wipeRight: function() { alert("right"); },
     wipeUp: function() { alert("up"); },
     wipeDown: function() { alert("down"); }
     preventDefaultEvents: true
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the #showme_id how do i get the id . or is this script in the loop.

Comment: You must be knowing the id of the element on which you want to attach the swipe event. Place this code at appropriate place in your code.

Comment: sorry if im not clear, in the first post i made the div id's are pulled from a database ie, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. if the javascript is in the header how to pull the id from the div to the javascript in the header. regards

Comment: I dont think so you can use touchwipe with live. In your case what you can do is run this script in a loop passing each of the ids from database response.

Comment: This is what i am currently doing, just wasn't sure if it was correct. i will look into touchswipe looks like i can have more control over the gestures. thanks again for your help. regards shane

Comment: This is really a good plugin for idevices and I am using it big time in my application, thanks anyways enjoy coding :)